# Convert multiple rows into single array

Tags: sql, arrays, subquery, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My current code returns `single-row error`

```
 SELECT TO_ARRAY(
SELECT 'o' || '.' || c.column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As c WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' AND  c.column_name NOT IN('COL_NAME'));
```

Sub-query returns each column as a row. When adding `LIMIT 1` I get almost desired result.
How to pick these rows and add them to array?

Expected result of running the query should be:

```
SELECT o.col_name1, o.col_name2... o.col_nameN FROM table_name As o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array, I would recommend `array_agg()`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG('o' || '.' || c.column_name)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' AND
      c.column_name NOT IN('COL_NAME'));
```